# Unable to Create Materialized View With Fast Refresh

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, materialized-views

Recently, I decided to take a look at Oracle's fast refresh features to speed up some materialized views. Here is what I got after following [this](https://www.discngine.com/blog/2020/8/10/materialized-view-fast-refresh) nice guide I found online:

1. I created materialized view logs for every table involved in the definition query

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON SIGNOS.DIRTY_TABLE WITH ROWID INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON SIGNOS.LOOKUP_TABLE WITH ROWID INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

2. Later on, I wrote the definition query considering all the requirements for fast refresh

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW SIGNOS.MV_FILTERED_DATA 
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND AS
    SELECT
    LT.ROWID AS LT_ROWID,
    DT.ROWID AS DT_ROWID,
    DT.ID,
    DT.SHAPE
FROM
    SIGNOS.LOOKUP_TABLE LT,
    SIGNOS.DIRTY_TABLE DT
WHERE
    LT.TABLE_ROWID (+) = DT.ROWID
    AND LT.TABLE_ROWID IS NULL
    AND LT.TABLE_NAME = 'SIGNOS.DIRTY_TABLE'
    AND LT.TABLE_SHAPE_FIELD_NAME = 'SHAPE';
-- SHAPE is an Oracle Spatial field
-- I am also not so sure about this LEFT ANTI-JOIN, I am quite new to Oracle syntax.
```

Unfortunately, Oracle keeps spitting out this error after the last snippet:

```
ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query
```

My IDE (DBeaver) highlights in red the line right after the `FROM` statement, around the first table definition (`SIGNOS.LOOKUP_TABLE LT,`).

**Edit 1:**

To give a little bit of context: this `LOOKUP_TABLE` is responsible for listing every invalid `ROWID` from every single table on this database. There are no valid primary keys in this system. Later on, using a left anti-join, I should be able to filter those undesired rows from the final materialized views.

**Edit 2:**

Following @Justin Cave suggestion, I executed the `dbms_mview.explain_mview` procedure and dumped the resulting table [here](https://gist.github.com/teofilosalgado/68b7674c2d3b7ec8d187b4af14950b1c) as a gist.

What could be causing this error?

TIA

Comment: Don't use `ROWID` for a join or store it as a foreign key. `ROWID` is a pseudo-column physical storage pointer for a row's location within a datafile; *it may change* if tables are reorganized. You need to join on real columns that exist for the data in your tables. Also, why join - especially an open join - if you're not going to select any data from `STATUS_GEOMETRIA`?

Comment: You can use `dbms_mview.explain_mview` to tell you why the materialized view isn't fast refreshable.  https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2020/09/dbms_mview-explain_mview-with-no-mv_capabilities_table/  If you included a reproducible test case, it would be much easier for someone to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @pmdba Desperate times call for desperate measures! All tables involved in this system have poorly designed and often violated primary keys. These materialized views will be used as a "clean" interface to those underlying tables. 
Now, about this join: I omitted some of the conditions for brevity but I will add then as an edit. Long story short, this system contains hundreds of geometric tables with broken geometries. To filter them out I created a lookup table `STATUS_GEOMETRIA` listing every single `ROWID` belonging to a problematic geometry that must be hidden from the end user.

Comment: @JustinCave I am working on a reproducible test case for the next edit. I am also working on a translated version of the snippets. Sorry for posting such a raw question. I was working on this task for hours! Oh, and thanks for the tip, I will give it a try!

Comment: @JustinCave I executed the `dbms_mview.explain_mview` procedure and dumped the resulting table [here](https://gist.github.com/teofilosalgado/68b7674c2d3b7ec8d187b4af14950b1c). It doesn't seem to be very clear on why fast refresh isn't available...

Comment: Please edit your question to include that output.  I'm guessing `shape` here is the object type that many of the restrictions reference.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 21c doesn't seem to support geometry fields in fast refresh materialized views - as @Justin Cave suspected. I will leave some snippets bellow showing how to reproduce this behaviour.

First of all, let's create a few simple tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE signos.lookup_table (
    objectid NUMBER (38) NOT NULL,
    table_rowid rowid NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE signos.dirty_table (
    objectid NUMBER (38) NOT NULL,
    shape MDSYS.GEOMETRY
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON signos.lookup_table WITH ROWID INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON signos.dirty_table WITH ROWID INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

This should work since we omitted the geometry field from the materialized view query:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW signos.mv_filtered REFRESH FAST ON
DEMAND WITH ROWID AS
SELECT
    dt.objectid,
    dt.rowid AS dt_rowid,
    lt.rowid AS lt_rowid
FROM
    signos.dirty_table dt,
    signos.lookup_table lt
WHERE
    lt.table_rowid (+) = dt.rowid
    AND lt.table_rowid IS NULL;
```

Unfortunately, we can't say the same about this one:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW signos.mv_filtered REFRESH FAST ON
DEMAND WITH ROWID AS
SELECT
    dt.objectid,
    dt.shape, -- !!!
    dt.rowid AS dt_rowid,
    lt.rowid AS lt_rowid
FROM
    signos.dirty_table dt,
    signos.lookup_table lt
WHERE
    lt.table_rowid (+) = dt.rowid
    AND lt.table_rowid IS NULL;
```

Which returns the same error:

```
ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query
```